# Filtering data of JSON file by multiple key ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

im building application using ionic 3 
i'm trying to get city with id_City and name_City

(this code is to get City with id_City only is work fine)

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.http.get("http://myURL/exmple.php").map(res => res.json().circuits).subscribe(data =>{
      this.City = data.filter(item => item.id_City === "1");   

      console.log(this.City);   
  })
```

}

How can I get the City with the (id_City) and (name_City)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression inside .filter() returns a boolean value and based on that data is filtered.
If you want multiple filtering criteria, just club multiple conditions using and(&&).
For eg:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.http.get("http://myURL/exmple.php")
    .map(res => res.json().circuits)
    .subscribe(data =>{
        this.City = data.filter(item => {
            return item.id_City === "1" && item.name_City === "1"
        });
        // this.City = data.filter(item => item.id_City === "1" && item.name_City === "1");
        console.log(this.City);   
  })
```